# LinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) causes lagging android app

Tags: android

i'm trying to make a linear layout visible when the user clicks on a marker on the map but everytime the user clicks on it the app slows down and after a few seconds it crashes,how can i solve this problem?
that's the linear layout i'm trying to make visible :

```
 <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/group"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:background="#80000000">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="7"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1">
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/addresse"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                          <LinearLayout
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="0dp"
                              android:layout_weight="1">
                              <TextView
                                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                  android:text="gelmj"
                                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                                  android:background="@color/black"
                                  android:layout_weight="1"

                                  />
                              <TextView
                                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                  android:text="gelmkhj"
                                  android:textColor="@color/black"
                                  android:background="@color/white"
                                  android:layout_weight="1"/>
                          </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:background="@color/red"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="3">
                            <ImageView
                                android:src="@drawable/parking"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
```

thanks.

Comment: well i think the issue with your java code (whatever you used) not xml.

Comment: that's what i used in java: LinearLayout group;
 group=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.group);
        group.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: it will be helpful if you posted the code and the error you have got.

Comment: can you provide your java code?

Comment: i forgot to mention that the linear layout does become visible but the problem is the lag and the crashing after it becomes visible,once i make it invisible the app works perfectly fine

Comment: **it will be helpful if you posted the code and the error you have got in the log.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to guess the problem without the code and the error log, but in most cases the lagging is caused when you try to load a high resolution image on a phone with low memory, and if the memory gets full an OutOfMemory exception is thrown which leads to an app crash. Try to reduce the size of the image in your ImageView or you can increase the memory heap alloted to your app:
In Manifests, add a property to the application tag: 
android:largeheap="true"

Comment: Hey,looks like you can help me in my case,  i'm getting data from api and also update it using pagination, now i'm showing two recyclerviews(simple recyclerView and Grid, by default is grid and list have VISIBILITY.GONE), when i get response i update both at the same time even while list is gone, but it's not lagging, now when i click on button to make list visible and grid gone, it lags too much and another time i switch it will not lag, so it looks like updating data in recyclerview when visibility is gone, it will not work, so it's loading data when i make it visible, am i right or not??

Comment: looks like i solved it according to whatever i'm thinking, i just replaced visibility to `invisible` from `gone` from layout file and it's working like charm..so i think yes, setting data in adapter/recyclerview only works properly if it's not `GONE`..